# Android Studio gradle exception flutter sdk not found

Tags: flutter, gradle

I am new and my problem is with gradle and its upgrades. I can't seem to run the app I am working on and emulator works but a black screen comes up with trying to run app. Only thing I notice is this code.

GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HNCHV.png)

Answer (score 0):

If you open Build.gradle using Flutter it will show this error, you can open Build.gradle using this method. Close this project >>  ***Open Existing Android Studio Project*** >> then go to your project and open Android Folder via Android Studio if you want to work on Build.gradle

additionally, just to be safe

make sure you have set flutter sdk in Environment setting by: RightClick on ThisPC >> Properties >> Advanced System Settings >> Environment Variables.

Comment: First I closed project then >> **_Open Existing Android Studio Project_**>> but couldn't find previous project and wasn't sure what folder it was in but looked and then you put to open _Android Folder_ via_Android Studio_ which I take is Android Studio then Android (Folder).   And I tried the last advice but didn't see Flutter SDK and I guess I would have to add, maybe I am doing it all wrong but like I said I am very new so I need it as easy as can be as far as steps so thank you @UmairJibran.

Comment: here, follow this, it might help you [YouTube Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qWd_YoM8wko&pbjreload=10)

Answer (score 0):

I think You have error in `build.gradle` - New Properties and Gradlexception.that's the way of Reslove the problem.

1. change `compileSdkVersion 30`
   and `targetSdkVersion 30` like this
2. Next go to `Project Structure` -> `project` -> `Project SDK` That place have view In no SDK.if Click dropDown and Select `Android API30  platform version`
3. Then Go to `Modules` Click `Module SDK` dropdown and Select `Android API30           platform version`
4. Then click Okay.
5. Now Sure first error is slove then add `throw new FileNotFoundException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")` Except this `throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")`

Thank you.Thats Help For you.

[image: LIke this]